# When seperating class file into .h and .cpp file how can I define it in the main file by including the .h file?

Tags: c++

So I'm implementing a simple test class and such I'm separating files into :
compte.h:

```
#ifndef COMPTE_H
#define COMPTE_H
#include <iostream>
class compte
{
public:
    static int n;
    int numCompte;
    char* nom;
    double solde;
public:
    compte(const char* = NULL, const double & = 0);
    ~compte();
};
```

and a compte.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "compte.h"
using namespace std;

int compte::n = 1000;
    
compte::compte(const char* nom, const double &solde)
{
    this->solde = solde;
    this->nom = new char[strlen(nom)];
    strcpy(this->nom, nom);

    numCompte = n++;
}
compte::~compte()
{
    delete[] nom;
}
```

however, when I include **compte.h** I get an unidentified reference to the member methods of the class, when I include **compte.cpp** it works, I just want to know what I can add to include the .h file instead of .cpp

Comment: How are you compiling? You need to compile both main.cpp and compte.cpp

Comment: Side note: compte.h doesn't need to `#include <iostream>`. Best practice is to include only the necessary headers with the declarations / type definitions / macros that are actually used.

Comment: You've used `public` twice in your class definition, are you sure the first wasn't supposed to be a `private`?

Comment: `new char[strlen(nom)]` is not enough for the copy including the final `'\0'`. Unless you have requirements not to, just use `std::string` and avoid all those details and mistakes.

Comment: If you are using VSCode in the default mode you need to modify `tasks.json` for it to use more than 1 source file. The default setting builds only the active file into an executable. The official documentation explains what change you need to make.

Comment: The code structure is fine (bugs aside). What is the *actual* error message you are seeing? There should be no *undeclated identifier* errors. Are you, by chance, seeing *unresolved external* errors instead? That happens if you don't compile and link the `.cpp` file into the final `.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header file `compte.h` is missing an `#endif` in the end.

```
#ifndef COMPTE_H
#define COMPTE_H
#include <iostream>
class compte
{
public:
    static int n;
    int numCompte;
    char* nom;
    double solde;
public:
    compte(const char* = NULL, const double & = 0);
    ~compte();
};

#endif
```

This is a sample of main file you can test with

```
#include "compte.h"
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<compte> account = make_unique<compte>("account", 100);
    cout << account->solde; 
}
```

Compile and run:

`g++ compte.h compte.cpp main.cpp -o main.exe`

`./main.exe`

Answer (score 1):

as a rule of thumb do NOT include *.c or *.cpp.
You should include only headers of f. (and classes for C++), since the extension: "headers"

including *.ccp may work, if you include it ONCE in only one other file (in you example near main()), but it can lead to duplication of identifiers, as including in 2 files, will produce TWO source code (work dine by preprocessor) so TWO functions (classes...) code, so link will complain about it.